# Flutter: From a tab pass some string to a specific tab and show that specific tab in tabbar

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a flutter project where I have 3 tabs in tabbar.
In tab 1 and tab 2, there are lists showing some data using ListView. When clicked on a list item, I want to pass some string to tab 3 and show tab 3.

Below is my home page code:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = new TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {},
      child: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("InstaPost"),
            backgroundColor: Colors.black45,
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  text: "Tab 1",
                ),
                Tab(text: "Tab 2"),
                Tab(text: "Tab 3"),
                // Tab(text: "My Posts")
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Tab1(),
              Tab2(),
              Tab3(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So, when the app is launched the first screen will be tab 1 which shows a list of names. The code is below

```
class _HashtagPageState extends State<HashtagPage> {

  Future<dynamic> getLists() async {
     // get list
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {},
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getLists(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Container(
              child: SpinKitDoubleBounce(color: Colors.green, size: 100),
            );
          } else {
            // log(snapshot.data.toString());
            var data = snapshot.data;
            return Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.separated(
                      itemCount: data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(data[index]),
                          onTap: () {
                              
                              // code to pass a string value to tab 3 and navigate to tab 3
                             
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When clicked on a list item in tab 1, how should I pass a string to tab 3 and navigate to tab 3 at the same time ?

Comment: Please share code in which you've attempted to solve this problem.

Comment: There are many ways to pass value from one to another, you can use constructor, arguments, or static variables. please provide more details or code so we can figure out your exact problem.

Comment: For anyone reading/basing on this code - note that the TabController "controller" object is never being used. The usage is mixed with the DefaultTabController - so mind your step :)

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use https://pub.dev/packages/provider 
Step 1: You can save parameter in `YourModel` 
Step 2: In `Tab3` , you can access with `(context.watch<YourModel>().parameter)` 
code snippet

```
class YourModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  String _parameter = "";
  String get parameter => _parameter;

  void passParameter(String parameter) {
    _parameter = parameter;
    print(_parameter);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
...
ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create: (context) => YourModel(),
  child: MyApp(),
),  
...
class Tab3 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text("${(context.watch<YourModel>().parameter)}"));
  }
}
...
return ListTile(
              title: Text(data[index]),
              onTap: () {
                Provider.of<YourModel>(context, listen: false)
                    .passParameter(data[index]);
                widget.controller.animateTo(2);
              },
            );
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class YourModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  String _parameter = "";
  String get parameter => _parameter;

  void passParameter(String parameter) {
    _parameter = parameter;
    print(_parameter);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => YourModel(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {},
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("InstaPost"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black45,
          bottom: TabBar(
            controller: controller,
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                text: "Tab 1",
              ),
              Tab(text: "Tab 2"),
              Tab(text: "Tab 3"),
              // Tab(text: "My Posts")
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: controller,
          children: <Widget>[
            HashtagPage(controller),
            Tab2(),
            Tab3(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Tab2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Tab2");
  }
}

class Tab3 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text("${(context.watch<YourModel>().parameter)}"));
  }
}

class HashtagPage extends StatefulWidget {
  TabController controller;

  HashtagPage(this.controller);
  @override
  _HashtagPageState createState() => _HashtagPageState();
}

class _HashtagPageState extends State<HashtagPage> {
  Future<List<String>> _future;

  Future<List<String>> getLists() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {});

    return Future.value(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _future = getLists();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {},
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: _future,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Container(
              child: SpinKitDoubleBounce(color: Colors.green, size: 100),
            );
          } else {
            // log(snapshot.data.toString());
            var data = snapshot.data;
            return Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.separated(
                      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                          Divider(),
                      itemCount: data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(data[index]),
                          onTap: () {
                            Provider.of<YourModel>(context, listen: false)
                                .passParameter(data[index]);
                            widget.controller.animateTo(2);
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

Set up the `TabController` as such:

```
child: Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
      bottom: TabBar(
        controller: _tabController, 
        tabs: ...,
      ),
    ),
  body: TabBarView(
    controller: _tabController,
    children: ...
```

And then to switch between tabs

```
  // Set desired state to cause changes in target tab
  setState(() {
    appState.targetValue = newValue;
  });

  // Important for the timing/sequence of the actions
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
    _tabController.animateTo(newTabIndex);
  });
```